# Why is the class of the result of integer division not an integer?

Tags: r, integer, numeric

I was playing with R integer division (%/%) and I have a question. When I do

```
class(as.integer(4) %/% 2)
```

The result is

```
[1] "numeric"
```

I expected

```
[1] "integer"
```

Why is the result of integer division not of class integer?

I noticed that when I change the divisor to integer, the result is integer. But I couldn't find anything in the documentation to explain why. Could anybody explain?

Comment: maybe in order to get 0.5 when you try to divide 2/4. Try to wrap the result in "as.integer" for your expected result

Comment: From `?"%/%"`, `Value` section: `If either argument is complex the result will be complex,
     otherwise if one or both arguments are numeric, the result will be
     numeric.  If both arguments are of type integer, the type of the
     result of ‘/’ and ‘^’ is numeric and for the other operators it is
     integer (with overflow, which occurs at +/- (2^31 - 1), returned
     as ‘NA_integer_’ with a warning).`.

Comment: It is because class(2) will give you numeric. This means that when you divide by a numeric you get a numeric, it wont coerce into an integer. But integer division just gives you a floor not class of an integer.

Comment: `class(as.integer(4) %/% 2L)`

Comment: @nicola: thanks! I missed that. Will look more closely next time.

Answer (score 2):

@Nicola provided the doc reference in the comments. I guess the answer is simply: operations involving numeric will stay numeric - only if both arguments are integer will the result remain integer. Thanks all!